# Docker desktop (WSL2 engine) fails to start after switching to windows containers on Windows 11 Home

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I am on Windows 11 Home Edition (21H2). Installed docker desktop 4.15.0 from https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/. After installation everything seemed to work fine. I was able to run `docker run hello-world` from powershell. But then I wanted to build a `Dockerfile` that used the microsoft image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019`

```
> docker build .
[...]
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019                                            0.2s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:058c8482946efa0b44b57e5ecebd7857b4df37a1365acdde32736628747ad9e1: not found
```

I searched documentation, see https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/windowsfaqs/#how-do-i-switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers :

> From the Docker Desktop menu, you can toggle which daemon (Linux or Windows) the Docker CLI talks to. Select Switch to Windows containers to use Windows containers, [...]

I followed this instruction to switch to Windows containers:

[image]

[image]

But after selecting "Switch" button (see screenshot above), docker desktop just says "Docker  desktop starting..." and nothing happens.

[image]

I checked the documentation again: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/ and ran the diagnostic tool:

```
> 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.diagnose.exe' check
[2022-12-19T00:09:41.668707400Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] set path configuration to OnHost
Starting diagnostics

[PASS] DD0027: is there available disk space on the host?
[PASS] DD0028: is there available VM disk space?
[PASS] DD0002: does the bootloader have virtualization enabled?
[SKIP] DD0018: does the host support virtualization?
[PASS] DD0001: is the application running?
[PASS] DD0017: can a VM be started?
[PASS] DD0016: is the LinuxKit VM running?
[FAIL] DD0011: are the LinuxKit services running? failed to ping VM diagnosticsd with error: Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerDiagnosticd: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2022-12-19T00:09:43.462307800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] ipc.NewClient: 5abd4d00-diagnose -> \\.\pipe\dockerDiagnosticd diagnosticsd
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.glob..func14()
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/linuxkit.go:18 +0x8b
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x10140c0)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x10140c0)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0x4?, 0x10140c0)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:142 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x3, 0x10140c0, 0xc00061f728)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:151 +0x87
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x1014140, 0xc00061f728)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:148 +0x52
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x10141c0, 0xc00061f728)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:148 +0x52
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x1014940, 0xc00061f728)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:148 +0x52
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x9b2c80?, 0xc00026f890)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:137 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x1014940, 0x3a35893600000010?, {0xc00026fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1d4
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000703d0?, 0xc0000703d0?, 0x4?}, {0x0, 0x0})
[       common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:133 +0x105
[main.main()
[       common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:99 +0x287
[2022-12-19T00:09:43.462865700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] (d1ae4863) 5abd4d00-diagnose C->S diagnosticsd GET /ping
[2022-12-19T00:09:43.463587400Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][W] (d1ae4863) 5abd4d00-diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (548.7µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerDiagnosticd: The system cannot find the file specified.

[FAIL] DD0023: is the Containers Windows Feature enabled? required Windows Feature not installed: Containers
[2022-12-19T00:09:43.465829700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] ipc.NewClient: b5ee5ef6-com.docker.diagnose -> \\.\pipe\dockerBackendV2 com.docker.service.exe
[common/pkg/windows/serviceclient.NewClientForPath(...)
[       common/pkg/windows/serviceclient/service.go:49
[common/pkg/windows/serviceclient.NewClient({0xa768bf, 0x13}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
[       common/pkg/windows/serviceclient/service.go:38 +0xc5
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.checkWindowsFeature({{0xa6e7d9?, 0x1?}, {0xa6e7d9?, 0x8d?}})
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/features_windows.go:11 +0x51
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.glob..func6()
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/dockerd_windows.go:11 +0x35
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x10142c0)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x10142c0)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0x4?, 0x10142c0)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:142 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x3, 0x10142c0, 0xc00061f728)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:151 +0x87
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x1014140, 0xc00061f728)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:148 +0x52
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x10141c0, 0xc00061f728)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:148 +0x52
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x1014940, 0xc00061f728)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:148 +0x52
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x9b2c80?, 0xc00026f890)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:137 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x1014940, 0x3a35893600000010?, {0xc00026fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1d4
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000703d0?, 0xc0000703d0?, 0x4?}, {0x0, 0x0})
[       common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:133 +0x105
[main.main()
[       common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:99 +0x287
[2022-12-19T00:09:43.465829700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] (d93b6fc4) b5ee5ef6-com.docker.diagnose C->S com.docker.service.exe POST /windowsfeatures/check: [Containers (Containers)]
[2022-12-19T00:09:43.939061900Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] (d93b6fc4) b5ee5ef6-com.docker.diagnose C<-S 5523a302-ServiceAPI POST /windowsfeatures/check (473.2322ms): {"NotAvailable":[{"Description":"Containers","Name":"Containers"}],"NotEnabled":[]}

[FAIL] DD0004: is the Docker engine running? Get "http://ipc/docker": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2022-12-19T00:09:43.940262800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] ipc.NewClient: a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose -> \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer VMDockerdAPI
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.NewClientForPath(...)
[       linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:61
[linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client.NewClient({0xa768bf, 0x13})
[       linuxkit/pkg/desktop-host-tools/pkg/client/client.go:55 +0x99
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.isDockerEngineRunning()
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/dockerd.go:21 +0x29
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.(*test).GetResult(0x1014140)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/test.go:46 +0x43
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run.func1(0x1014140)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:17 +0x5a
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce.func1(0x3?, 0x1014140)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:142 +0x77
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x2, 0x1014140, 0xc00061f728)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:151 +0x87
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x1, 0x10141c0, 0xc00061f728)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:148 +0x52
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkDepthFirst(0x0, 0x1014940, 0xc00061f728)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:148 +0x52
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.walkOnce(0x9b2c80?, 0xc00026f890)
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:137 +0xcc
[common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose.Run(0x1014940, 0x3a35893600000010?, {0xc00026fb20, 0x1, 0x1})
[       common/pkg/diagkit/gather/diagnose/run.go:16 +0x1d4
[main.checkCmd({0xc0000703d0?, 0xc0000703d0?, 0x4?}, {0x0, 0x0})
[       common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:133 +0x105
[main.main()
[       common/cmd/com.docker.diagnose/main.go:99 +0x287
[2022-12-19T00:09:43.940869400Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] (0277e282) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C->S VMDockerdAPI GET /docker
[2022-12-19T00:09:43.941441100Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][W] (0277e282) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /docker (571.7µs): Get "http://ipc/docker": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2022-12-19T00:09:43.942116600Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] (0277e282-1) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C->S VMDockerdAPI GET /ping
[2022-12-19T00:09:43.942116600Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][W] (0277e282-1) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (0s): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2022-12-19T00:09:44.951299700Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] (0277e282-2) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C->S VMDockerdAPI GET /ping
[2022-12-19T00:09:44.952368100Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][W] (0277e282-2) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (1.0684ms): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2022-12-19T00:09:45.966443900Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] (0277e282-3) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C->S VMDockerdAPI GET /ping
[2022-12-19T00:09:45.967076400Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][W] (0277e282-3) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (632.5µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2022-12-19T00:09:46.978045300Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] (0277e282-4) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C->S VMDockerdAPI GET /ping
[2022-12-19T00:09:46.979132400Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][W] (0277e282-4) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (1.2815ms): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2022-12-19T00:09:47.984015000Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] (0277e282-5) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C->S VMDockerdAPI GET /ping
[2022-12-19T00:09:47.985051200Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][W] (0277e282-5) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (1.0362ms): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2022-12-19T00:09:48.991994000Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] (0277e282-6) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C->S VMDockerdAPI GET /ping
[2022-12-19T00:09:48.993515900Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][W] (0277e282-6) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (1.0491ms): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2022-12-19T00:09:49.999431800Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] (0277e282-7) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C->S VMDockerdAPI GET /ping
[2022-12-19T00:09:50.000430100Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][W] (0277e282-7) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (998.3µs): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2022-12-19T00:09:51.020341400Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][I] (0277e282-8) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C->S VMDockerdAPI GET /ping
[2022-12-19T00:09:51.021623100Z][com.docker.diagnose.exe][W] (0277e282-8) a1bc4120-com.docker.diagnose C<-S NoResponse GET /ping (1.2817ms): Get "http://ipc/ping": open \\.\pipe\dockerLifecycleServer: The system cannot find the file specified.

[PASS] DD0015: are the binary symlinks installed?
[FAIL] DD0031: does the Docker API work? error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine_linux/v1.24/containers/json?limit=0": open //./pipe/docker_engine_linux: The system cannot find the file specified.
[PASS] DD0013: is the $PATH ok?
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
[FAIL] DD0003: is the Docker CLI working? exit status 1
[PASS] DD0005: is the user in the docker-users group?
2022/12/19 01:09:51 exit status 0xffffffff
```

From the above output I see:

```
[FAIL] DD0023: is the Containers Windows Feature enabled? required Windows Feature not installed: Containers
```

I tried to search the documentation for more information on this, but was not able to find any good advice. Any idea what is going on here?